# Best practices for answering a question with information copied from another website

Tags: discussion

I recently found a website with an excellent list of open data links. I wanted to provide part of this list as an answer to [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data).

I copied the relevant portion of the list (including descriptions) verbatim into [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/14094/19566). I included a link to the original website, mentioned the name of the author of that website, and included a link to donate to keep that website alive.

Sometimes websites go away, so if I just provided a link to the original website then my answer could become useless in the future.

Normally I would try to add some value to the information, but the original list is so well-described that putting it into my own words seems like it could only make it worse, not better.

Was that okay? What could/should I have done instead?

TL;DR: Is it okay to directly copy from another website to answer a question here?

Answer (score 1):

> Was that okay?

100% fine by me.

> Is it okay to directly copy from another website to answer a question here?

Yes.

---

(another option is to use the "[Save Page Now](https://help.archive.org/hc/en-us/articles/360001513491-Save-Pages-in-the-Wayback-Machine)" feature or archive.org, if you don't want to type everything out here.)

Comment: Thank you for the "save page now" suggestion; I used it immediately. I had heard of the Wayback Machine, but I assumed it ran on fairydust and magic (like the rest of the internet). I didn't realize I could add pages to it myself.

Comment: i use a bookmarklet to add everything to the wayback machine. its the best!